# Replacing Text in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm need of a tiny help.I have a get statement on my process form like this

```
<?php echo $_GET['search']?>
```

Now how do i put "+" sign in between the spaces.Because what my current code does is  just gets the data from the text of another form.

I would be glad if you could help.

Thanking You,

Answer (score -3, accepted):

$newText=str_replace(' ', ' + ', $_GET['search']);

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will replace the text as desired and save the new updated string in $newText

Comment: same answer already given TWICE :>

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php echo str_replace(' ', ' + ', $_GET['search']) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function this way:

```
$new_text = str_replace(' ', ' + ', $_GET['search']);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about input that looks like

```
hello  world
```

(two spaces between the words)? Do you want to get `hello +  + world` ?

If not, I suggest to remove the white spaces from the beginning and the end of the string first and use a regular expression to substitute several following white spaces with one `+`:

```
preg_replace('#\s+#', ' + ', trim($_GET['search']))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to modify a regex to match more than just spaces.

```
function insertPlusSign($str)
{
    $func = create_function('$c', 'return $c . '+' . $c;');
    return preg_replace_callback('/ /', $func, $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use urlencode, which also encodes the string to be used in a query part of a URL

```
echo urlencode('word1 word2 word3 word4 wiérdText@');
// Output: word1+word2+word3+word4+wi%E9rdText%40
```

Comment: Oops I think i missread the question :(